# Is it possible for Insert and delete queries to escape from Lock wait timeout?

Tags: mysql

In my project, I'm using innodb storage engine with isolation level READ-COMMITTED. 
And Iam having my **innodb_lock_wait_timeout** as 300s (5 min). For select and update queries, if they waited for lock held by other transactions, after 5 min, I'm getting

> "Lock wait timeout..Try restarting Transaction."

But for insert queries (delete query sometimes), even after 5 min I'm not getting lock wait timeout.
Just after 5 min, if I kill those insert query, I get the exception based on connection termination which is expected but in

> "show processlist"

the query is marked as killed but the query seems to be remain for more than an hour or two. 
Is there any configuration parameters causing this or something else. Googled such problems but can't find the right answer.

**FYI**:
I'm just inserting 1 row(not bulk insert)which is waiting to acquire lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When further digged and debugged, it was found that it was an issue with the mysql version 5.7.18. When updated with 5.7.24 the query waiting for lock can actually throw "lock wait timeout exceeded. Try restarting transaction".